# Модуль CRUD для Kohana 3.3

Tags: kohana

Существует ли модуль `CRUD` для `Kohana 3.3`, более менее работающий, без использования посторонних плагинов?

Comment: Чем тебе встроенный database/orm не устраивает?

Comment: устраивает всем ,я наверное не так выразился ,есть модули которые по модели ,реализуют админ-часть приложения ,т.е все основные типичные операции (удалить/создать/редактировать) вид наподобие phpmyadmin'a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, скорее всего такого модуля в Вашем понимании нет, ибо он бессмыслен. В Kohana и так обычные операции CRUD делаются несколькими строками.

Есть такие модули как [formo](https://github.com/bmidget/kohana-formo), которые позволяют по структуре модели создать страницу добавления/редактирования, еще по-моему в Jelly была такая возможность. (Это если Вы вдруг это имеете ввиду)